# Next js 13: Module not found. Error during building

Tags: javascript

I get this error when building the application (next build). If you run 'next dev' first, the build will be successful. But this is very inconvenient in production.

Tell me how this can be fixed?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BThhu.png)

I tried deleting the folder .next, but it didn't help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to version 13.5.6 solved the problem